# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2}{(7x^3+2)^2} dx$ using u substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.2

Can somebody verify my solution? Thanks!!

Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2}{(7x^3+2)^2} dx$ using u substitution

---

Let $u=7x^3+2$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=21x^2$ and so $\frac{du}{21x^2}=dx$.

Thus we have:

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{x^2}{(7x^3+2)^2} \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \int \frac{x^2}{u^2} \frac{du}{21x^2}\,dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{21} \int \frac{1}{u^2} \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{21} \int u^{-2} \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{21} \frac{u^{-1}}{-1}+C \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{-1}{21} u^{-1}+C \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{-1}{21} (7x^3+2)^{-1}+C \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{-1}{21(7x^3+2)}+C
\end{align}

Comment: Looks good! what else are you looking for?

Comment: Just solution verification. This is for my students.

Comment: Ohh, I guess due to Corona shutdown... Nice initiative

Comment: Just saying, Wolfram Alpha is really good if you just want to check the answer

Comment: If find it odd to go through $u^{-2}$. I think $\int \frac 1{u^2}=-\frac 1u$ is sufficiently common to write it directly. Eventually do it on the side if some students have doubts.

Comment: Please recognise that all of your questions posted recently boil down to integrand like $f(g(x))g'(x)$ with primitive $F(g(x))$.  In this case: $\int \frac{x^2}{(7x^3+2)^2} dx=\frac{1}{21}\int 21x^2(7x^3+2)^{-2} dx$ with $f(x)=x^{-2}$ and $g(x)=7x^3+2$.  Hence a primitive is $\frac{1}{21}(-1)(7x^3+2)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out and I got the same answer you did.

One thing to point out: When you have $$\dfrac {du}{dx} = 21 x^2$$ you can write the subsitution as either $$\dfrac {du}{21 dx} = x^2$$ if you prefer to use $\dfrac {du}{dx}$ notation or $$\dfrac {1}{21}du = x^2 dx$$ if you prefer differential notation.

Comment: If you set $u=7x^3+2$, then $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(7x^3=2)=21x^2$. What differential operator are we applying to both sides to skip right to equality $\frac{du}{21}=x^2dx$? I'm legitimately curious, i'm studying differential forms right now and feel like there is a step here that is not fully explained in standard calculus sequences.

Comment: I've edited my reply above.  I'm so used to using "$? du = dx$" for subsitutions that I don't realize that some students haven't used differentials yet.

What I did see was $\frac {du}{21x^2} = dx$ might throw some students off (they might say, "why is there an $x$ with the $u$?").